# how to group the chart

Tags: mysql, web, charts, chart.js

i want to group this chart like " gender 1" is men  and "gender 2" is women, but when i try to code the chart it's difficult to differentiate them. [image: ![this is the picture]

here is my code

//data.php

```
<?php
//setting header to json
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//database
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'dbintegrasi');

//get connection
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if(!$mysqli){
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}

//query to get data from the table
$query = sprintf("SELECT JenisKelaminID, COUNT(JenisKelaminID) as jumlah FROM tahunmasukmagister GROUP BY JenisKelaminID");

//execute query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row){
    $data[] = $row;
}

//freee memory associated with result
$result->close();

//close connection
$mysqli->close();

//new print the data
print json_encode($data);
```

//app.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/chartjs/data.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var Gender = [];
            var jumlah = [];

            for(var i in data){
                Gender.push("Gender " + data[i].JenisKelaminID);
                jumlah.push(data[i].jumlah);

            }

            var chartdata = {
                labels: Gender,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label : 'Gender',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(250, 300, 100, 0.75)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: jumlah
                    }
                ]
            };

            var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

            var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartdata

            });
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

please help me to solve this, thankyou

Comment: Do you want a stacked bar chart or just bars with different colors?

Comment: i want bar chart with different color Jeff Carey, could you please help me to solve the codes? @jeffcarey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you app.js file on line number 10 :

```
Gender.push("Gender " + data[i].JenisKelaminID);
```

you can set an if condition instead of it Like

```
if(data[i].JenisKelaminID == 1){
Gender.push("Men");
} else if(data[i].JenisKelaminID == 2){
Gender.push("Women");
} else {
Gender.push("Other");
}
```

In there the chart name is defined, hope it will help your work.

Comment: btw, do you know how to differentiate them by colors?

Comment: @r0707637 Take a look at the example at http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-introduction . You can supply an array of backgroundColor's.